# Детский вопрос о прилагательных «ледяной» и «ледовый»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, прилагательные, выбор-варианта

Девочка подросла и сейчас часто сама находит нужную ей информацию.
*Что такое скелетон?* Ответ есть в Википедии ([*скелетон*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD)).

Но уточняющий детский вопрос все же возник: **ледяной** желоб или **ледовый**?

Вот выдержки:
**Скелето́н** (устар. **ске́летон**; англ. *skeleton* с греч. «скелет, каркас») — зимний олимпийский вид спорта, представляющий собой спуск по ***ледяному*** жёлобу на двухполосных санях на укреплённой раме...
Теперь нужно проехать примерно 1500 м. (зависит от трассы) вниз по ***ледовому*** желобу.

Так какие же они все-таки (желоба, трассы, спуски...) — ледяные или ледовые?

Comment: https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200404602

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку — пользительна. Вот только выводы сделать мне так и не удалось.

Comment: Короче, между ними произошла диффузия. У меня такой вывод получился (ещё до прочтения этого материала): "ледовой" об очень большом изо льда, а "ледяной" об остальном (что поменьше). Это если рассматривать значение, в котором они пересекаются.

Comment: Я попыталась найти конструкцию... Получается, вообще-то, что это *железобетонный* желоб (в качестве основы), на который заливают воду или намораживают лед. Вот здесь: (http://grm-group.com/objects/detail/10) и здесь: (https://arch-sochi.ru/2011/12/zavershen-betonnyiy-zhelob-sanno-bobsleynoy-trassyi/). Скелетоновский желоб не изо льда, а *покрыт* льдом. Я совсем запуталась в рассуждениях.

Comment: Ну тогда ледяной, как дорога, дорожная трасса. Но может быть, вопрос терминологии, надо у спортсменов спросить. Возможно и что оба варианта верные. Но в тексте, конечно, должна быть последовательность.

Comment: Думаю, размер и здесь может играть значение.

Comment: Про бобслей: 1. Бобсле́й — зимний олимпийский вид спорта, представляющий собой скоростной спуск с гор по специально оборудованным **ледовым трассам** на управляемых санях — бобах. 2 . Трасса для бобслея представляет собой **ледяной желоб** на железобетонном основании, имеющий различные по крутизне повороты и виражи. P. S. У спортсменов, думаю, свой сленг.

Comment: Хм, то же самое, а слова разные.

Answer (score 3):

- Ледяной = состоящий или сделанный из льда. *Ледяная глыба*, *Ледяной городок*
- Ледовый = имеет какое-либо отношение ко льду. *Ледовый дворец* (не дворец изо льда, а каток в нём ледяной).

Если я правильно понял, то этот жёлоб состоит изо льда, то есть правильней будет...

> спуск по ледяному жёлобу

Comment: ледовый -ая, -ое. 1) а) Состоящий изо льда; ледяной. *Ледовый покров.* Они пересекаются в этом значении.

Comment: @Зонтик Спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, ледовые - чаще объекты, которые находятся на льдах. "Ледяной" чаще применяется в переносном значении или в прямом, когда что-то состоит изо льда. К желобу, на мой взгляд, применимо "ледяной", т.к. он "изо льда".

Comment: "Изо льда" больше о "ледовом".

Comment: @ЮлияМ И Вам, Юлия, спасибо.